# Unable to install Ubuntu on a new SSD hardware drive

Tags: boot, ssd

I have a `Dell Latitude 7400` laptop with `256 GB SSD` drive and had a windows 10 installed earlier. I took backup of the contents and replaced it with `1 TB SSD` drive.

I was expecting the installation to go smooth with the bootable ubuntu USB, but after a few steps of the boot sequence, I ended up getting the following message

```
you need at least 8.6 gb to install ubuntu. this computer has only 4.0 gb
```

So, surely it is not able to recognise my brand new `1 TB SSD` drive.

I went to a laptop repair shop and the repair guy suggested it might be because it did not find the FAT32 partition. He suggested to first create this partition using a windows bootable usb and then, when the partition is created, boot it from the ubuntu usb.

I am not sure if this is the right/only way to install Ubuntu.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Which versions of Ubuntu did you tried?

Comment: Check in the computer's BIOS/UEFI settings and note down how the SSD is set up. It should be set as AHCI and not RAID.

Comment: @N0rbert I think its Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS

Comment: @user68186 Ok thanks, will check that.

Comment: Brilliant, it worked by changing to AHCI!